# Logging in with android app using Json and phpmyadmin

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I try to log in when clicking the button. I can see from the log that I have entered the correct entries. But it stays in this activity.

Here is the LoginActivity.java(When i press login, i get toast message: STAP 3):

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.i("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "STAP 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent myactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            myactivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(myactivity);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "STAP 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error logging innnn!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "STAP 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

Here is the UserFunctions.java:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    public JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = "-----";
    private static String registerURL = "------";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        JSONObject json;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public JSONObject logoutUser(Context context){
        JSONObject json;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", null));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", null));
        json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return json;
    }

}
```

logcat:

```
12-04 21:32:22.730      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for success
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:67)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-04 21:32:22.790      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-04 21:32:22.820      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-04 21:32:22.820     898-1224/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer E/JSON﹕ {"error_msg":"Connected "}{"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"548108d1662e68.06979757","user":{"name":"pok","email":"pok","created_at":"2014-12-05 02:22:25","updated_at":null}}
12-04 21:32:22.820      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 21:32:22.820      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 21:32:22.840      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-04 21:32:22.840      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-04 21:32:22.860      898-898/com.example.thelegendaryturk.theneckoptimizer W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I ran this code locally on a phpmyadmin, it worked. I swapped to the database in the cloud and it does not work anymore... Any help is welcome as I am wasting my time for hours now....

To make it a bit more clear: It does not access the if statement within try{}

Comment: What does the logcat show?

Comment: I added the logcat when i trie to login with username@gmail.com

Comment: You are getting "Stap 3" for a reason, your JSON is not formated correctly and that is why it goes to your catch clause, to elaborate more, check your php file if you are accessing the correct database. Since you said you swapped the database. try checking that, and your json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) is not a string, it's a integer

Comment: I got another log, it was the wrong one

Comment: There's the problem. the "KEY_SUCCESS" is not a string, it's an integer, try json.getInt.

Comment: I tried: 
json != null && json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS) != 0
Sorry, it gives NPE

Comment: And I noticed your json format is invalid. you can check it yourself here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and paste your JSON. reformat your json file.

Comment: Which file do I need to paste on that website? Im familiar with the C language, learning java from C is hard than I thought.

Comment: paste this in the site: {"error_msg":"Connected "}{"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"548108d1662e68.06979757","user":{"name":"pok","email":"pok","created_at":"2014-12-05 02:22:25","updated_at":null}}

Comment: WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOTTTTT

YOU ARE THE MAN SIR!!!!!! Thanks you really reallyyy much

Comment: Your welcome and Goodluck mate. :)